# How Do I exclude files of similar names from an Ant build script?

Tags: apache, ant, build, build.xml

I'm converting LESS to CSS via an ant build script. I want to only convert a LESS file if I haven't already converted that file previously.

How do I check one folder for the CSS file and then exclude that LESS file from the fileset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say how you're converting the files, but assuming you have a conversion task that operates on a fileset, you'd need a [depend selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#dependselect), something like this:

```
<fileset dir="less">
    <include name="**/*.less" />
    <depend targetdir="css">
        <globmapper from="*.less" to="*.css" />
    </depend>
</fileset>
```

That will only include .less files under the `less` directory that don't have a corresponding .css file in the `css` directory.  In addition, if a .less file is newer than the corresponding .css file it will be included in the fileset for conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm away from the office until Monday where I'll try your suggestion.